# Schema-less dbms that supports SQL query syntax

Tags: sql, database, schemaless

Is there any schema-less dbms that support SQL query syntax? RDBMSs support sql languages, noSQL DBMSs are schema less. But is there any schema less that support a query language similar to sql?

Answer (score 0):

I found http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql

> N1QL presents easy and familiar abstractions to quickly develop scalable applications that work with next generation database systems. It allows for filter expressions, aggregate expressions and many other features to build a rich application. Go ahead and give N1QL a spin!

also: http://crlog.info/2011/06/13/cassandra-query-language-cql-v1-0-0-updated/

Answer (score 0):

Djondb (http://djondb.com) supports a language similar to SQL called DQL (document query language), although it's similar in some ways you'll find that most of these languages are oriented to documents rather than columns and rows, hope this help you on your search